# How to get netbeans update modules

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I always downloaded netbeans modules (for the update center of my Netbeans Platform app) using

```
wget -r -N http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.3.1/uc/final/distribution/
```

now it seems that place is down. Instead, netbeans Plugins dialog points to

http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

but when I try to download that file (all `wget .../distribution/`) I get:

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Software caused connection abort) in headers.

Are they blocking it? Do I need to use some special port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was just a temporary issue. Both of the links work now (http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/ redirecting to http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/)